# Trying to move elements in an array instead replaces elements

Tags: c#, arrays

So, my assignment is that I have to make a program that changes a string and places it in the right order. Now, it is only allowed to do 3 things, one of which I have a question about. It is  allowed to take the second character and move it to the third, etc., until you arrive at the second to last character. This one gets replaced by the third to last character. So, abcdef would become aebcdf. My code gives me as output aebbbf. I have this:

```
class Program{
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        char[] characters = new char[input.Length];
        characters = input.ToCharArray();

        string answer = Console.ReadLine();

        if (answer == "x")
        {
            p.MethodX(characters);
            string s = new string(characters);
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

And the method MethodX:

```
public void MethodeX(char[] input)
    {
        int lengthText = input.Length;
        char temp = input[lengthText - 2];

        for (int i = 1; i < input.Length - 2; i++)
        {
            input[i + 1] = input[i];
            input[1] = temp;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: It sounds a lot like [Bubblesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

Comment: Your question seems to be [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at what the method does, exactly.

Assuming the string is `abcdef`, the derived array has the length 6. 6-2 is 4, so temp should be e - which is correct.

Now the iteration starts at 1, so b. 2, so array element 3 (c), gets replaced by b.

Next iteration: The next character after array element 2 (b) is now also b... As c got replaced by b. So d gets replaced by b, also!

And same goes for e. Output: `aebbbf`.

A solution could be this:

```
public char[] Xmethod(char[] input)
{
    char[] outputArray = input;
    char temp = input[6-2];
    for(int i = 1; i < input.Length -2; i++) 
    {
        outputArray[i+1] = input[i]; 
    }
    outputArray[1] = temp;
    return outputArray
}
```

Hope this helped.

EDIT: in an earlier version I made a mistake when creating the outputArray. It is fixed now.